# How can I await multiple tasks at the same time inside policy circuit breaker in c#?

Tags: c#, task, circuit-breaker

I wasn't able to find an answer to this question. Please help.
**Scenario**
I can wait for multiple tasks at a time by using Task.WhenAll. But I want it inside a policy circuit breaker `execution` method. Below is the code snippet. I am calling an API 2 times and wanted to get the call results at a time. Without circuit breaker, it is working, and I can use the results later in my code. But I do not understand how I can call the API using `Task.WhenAll` inside circuit breaker.

```
var param1 = new Param
{
    Category = Category.Manager,
    FirstName = "John",
    Address = "Sydney",
};
var param2 = new Param
{
    Category = Category.Officer,
    FirstName = "Adam",
    Address = "Melbourne",
};
```

**Working code:**

```
var results1 = Task.WhenAll(_apiClient.GetAsync(param1), _apiClient.GetAsync(param2));
//At this point results1 is NOT null and contains 2 items in it
```

***Problem:***

```
var results2 = _policyCircuitBreaker.Execute(()=> Task.WhenAll(_apiClient.GetAsync(param1), _apiClient.GetAsync(param2)));
//at this point results2 is of type Task, how can I get the results2 similar to results1
```

Comment: Task.Unwrap(results2) maybe?

Comment: If the question was about the [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/) circuit-breaker, might be worth the OP tagging the question with 'Polly', to confirm that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to store a reference to the Tasks outside of your `_policyCircuitBreaker` call.

```
var param1Task = _apiClient.GetAsync(param1);
var param2Task = _apiClient.GetAsync(param2);

Task results = _policyCircuitBreaker.Execute(() => Task.WhenAll(param1Task, param2Task));
```

Either await the circut breaker call, or use a continuation to get the results when they are completed.

### Await example:

```
await results;
var param1ApiResult = param1Task.Result;
var param2ApiResult = param2Task.Result;
```

### Continuation example (for code paths that can't be awaited)

```
results.ContinueWith(finishedTask =>
{
    var param1ApiResult = param1Task.Result; 
    var param2ApiResult = param2Task.Result;
});
```

Both examples will give you the results - you just need to store a reference to each Task, before you execute them in the `WhenAll` call. That lets you get their results later once the `Tasks` have completed.

I'm making some assumptions because your post wasn't clear as to what API you are trying to use nor what the Execute methods API looks like.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was able to get the results now.

Answer (score 2):

In general, as Johnathon Sullinger says, if you have a `Task<TResult>` and want to obtain the result of that `Task` in a non-blocking way, `await`-ing that `Task<TResult>` (or using a continuation) is the way to go.

Assuming however your circuit-breaker is from [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/), the formulation from the original question (repeated below) will not give the async circuit-breaker behaviour you likely want:

```
var results = _policyCircuitBreaker.Execute(() => Task.WhenAll(param1Task, param2Task));
```

That formulation uses the synchronous `.Execute(...)`: the `.Execute(...)` call through `_policyCircuitBreaker` will thus only govern `Task.WhenAll(...)` *synchronously* (near-immediately) *returning the* `Task<[]>` which represents waiting for the inner tasks to complete. The circuit-breaker will *not* (in this formulation) govern your calls to `_apiClient.GetAsync(...)`.

Assuming your intention is that the circuit-breaker should govern both the calls `_apiClient.GetAsync(param1)` and `_apiClient.GetAsync(param2)` (ie respond to faults those calls may raise), you need to use Polly's async-native policies and `.ExecuteAsync()` overloads:

```
var results3 = await _policyCircuitBreaker.ExecuteAsync(() => Task.WhenAll(_apiClient.GetAsync(param1), _apiClient.GetAsync(param2))));
```

`.ExecuteAsync(...)` internally awaits the delegate you have supplied while applying the policy behaviour (in this case circuit-breaker behaviour) to it.